# how to get url of the current page in c# (it has # symbol inside)

Tags: c#-4.0

How to get full URL using C#? This an example of my url-yes it has # symbol

http://domain.com/dude#hello

I've tried everything but I can't get the #hello. Any ideas? I've also used this link but no luck http://www.cambiaresearch.com/c4/dfdb20ae-b335-48ae-a201-f2a5a8329342/How-Do-I-Get-Paths-and-URL-fragments-from-the-HttpRequest-object.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Url fragments are purely client-side thing. They're not supposed to be used on the server side, which is why they're not passed through - not really usable anyway.

Comment: Hmm you are right-I can retrieve this info via js. I was just wondering if there was way to do this server side.